# Google Maps api v3 fixed position, only zoom

Tags: api, cordova, maps

I want to have only one fixed position in center, don't allow scroll left or right but zoom in or out. I have a circle in center of the fixed position, which should change radius equal to zoom in or out. So the radius of the circle should change with zooming in or out of the map.

I already got this work by a slider where I updated the radius with the value of the range I set in slider.

Would be great if somebody know a eventhandler or something else where the radius rise or decrease by zoom in or out smoothly.

I want to integrate this in my phonegap/cordova app, so that it works with touch gestures because I already tested setting the window to center it permanently in a endless loop. But it looks very buggy.